Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin in Android studio
I get the following error when trying to compile my module with Android Studio:
/home/myuser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio-jvm/3.6.0/5600569133b7bdefe1daf9ec7f4abeb6d13e1786/okio-jvm-3.6.0.jar!/META-INF/okio.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1

So in my module I have the following direct dependencies:
// OkHttp
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0"

// stetho
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.6.0'

// retrofit: library for api call
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

Now, retrofit depends on okhttp, and setho-okhttp also seems to install okhttp. And all okhttp modules depend on okio!
I'm not really adept in Kotlin android, so this gets a bit over my head. How is gradle dealing with this and why do I get this error?

It's more than likely the wrong version of the Kotlin plugin being applied. So it's a build plugin, not a dependency. Look in both your app build.gradle and root build.gradle files for where this is defined.
